# SQL handle leak on .Net 4.0 but not on .Net 3.5

Tags: sql, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, resource-leak

Following sample code leaks handles. Handle count started at 133, and in less than 2hrs it reached 900. Sample is VS2010 and .Net 4.0. This does not happen on .Net 3.5.
I have reproduced this on more than 3 machines, all Win2008 R2 servers. Both SQL 2008 & SQL 2012. These machines are VMs and are constantly rolled back twice a week, so are clean.

```
//Reference dll are the ones required for SQL 
//.Net 4.0 (not 'Client Profile' version)
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string sss = "Data Source=WIN-0BDHQ0IIUFL,1433;Initial Catalog=DB_Mycentral;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Myuser;Password=123;Connect Timeout=60;Network Library=dbmssocn";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sss);
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        i++;

        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} hrs sleep", i);
    }
}
```

I have observed activity in ProcMon.exe and call-stack in ProcExp.exe. ProcMon.exe logged CreateThread() and ExitThread() **repeatedly**. Then ProcExp.exe showed
**cld.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x18910** against the newly created TID. In the end THREAD object count in ProcExp.exe got bumped by one. This whole process repeats again and again.

```
Example for leaking of TID 9089:
CreateThread()/ExitThread() TID:9089 //Log in ProcMon.exe
cld.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x18910  TID: 9089  //Call-stack in ProcExp.exe
```

Background: I wrote this sample to narrow down a leak in our production code. That code worked fine in .Net 3.5 but leaks in .Net 4.0.

Please let me know if I have to set extra flags while opening connections.

Comment: You are relying on the finalizer (since you aren't disposing), so unless the garbage collector runs, you won't get finalized. http://dotnettips.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/net-4-0-bug-with-sqlconnection-object/

Comment: Considering the time it took to write the question, googling for SqlConnection Leak Handle would have been better... It seems it's quite famous. This shows that when you have a proble, first google.

Comment: Thank you Kopp. I will try the solution suggested by MS.

Comment: The code shown only opens one connection ever. It should not leak. The previous comments should not apply.

Comment: Usr2: Yes it open only connection but still leaks. Verified on couple of machines.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'using' to ensure that the dispose method is always called.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

```
//Reference dll are the ones required for SQL 
//.Net 4.0 (not 'Client Profile' version)
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string sss = "Data Source=WIN-0BDHQ0IIUFL,1433;Initial Catalog=DB_Mycentral;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Myuser;Password=123;Connect Timeout=60;Network Library=dbmssocn";
    using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sss))
    {

        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            i++;

            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} hrs sleep", i);
        }
    }
}
```